# How to derive the sine formula from the cross product

Tags: cross-product

Use the cross product to show that sinthetaA÷vector BC = Sin thetaB÷vector AC

Comment: By vector do you mean the length?

Comment: The length isn't specified, it's just the letters

Comment: The law of sines?

Comment: Does it say vector or does it have a bar over the AC per say?

Comment: Seems like you want the proof for the Law of Sines.

Comment: It's has the arrow

Comment: Yes proof but using the dot product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Equate the area of triangle

$$\lvert\vec{AC}\times\vec{AB}\rvert=\lvert\vec{BA}\times\vec{BC}\rvert\\
\lvert\vec{AC}\rvert\ \lvert\vec{AB}\rvert \sin{\theta_{A}}=\lvert\vec{BA}\rvert\ \lvert\vec{BC}\rvert \sin{\theta_{B}}\\
\lvert\vec{AC}\rvert\ \sin{\theta_{A}}= \lvert\vec{BC}\rvert \sin{\theta_{B}}$$

Comment: Oh ok now I understand. Thanks a lot